# Splitting up data file in Java Scanner

Tags: java, design-patterns, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I have the following data which I want to split up.

```
(1,167,2,'LT2A',45,'Weekly','1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13'),
```

to obtain each of the values:

> 1
>   167
>   2
>   'LT2A'
>   45
>   'Weekly'
>   '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13'

I am using the Scanner class to do that and with **,** as the delimiter.
But I face problems due to the last string: `('1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13')`.

I would hence like some suggestions on how I could split this data.
I have also tried using ,' as the delimiter but the string contains data without ''.

The question is quite specific to my needs but I would appreciate if someone could give me   suggestions on how I could split this data up.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658538/regular-expression-replace-all-commas-between-double-quotes similar question

Answer (score 2):

you can use simple logic for example:

```
    String str="1,167,2,'LT2A',45,'Weekly','1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13'";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(str);
    s.useDelimiter(",");
    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        String element = s.next();
        if(element.startsWith("'") && ! element.endsWith("'"))
        {
            while(s.hasNext())
            {
                element += "," + s.next();
                if(element.endsWith("'"))
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(element);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    String s = "1,167,2,'LT2A',45,'Weekly','1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13'";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    sc.useDelimiter(",");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String n = sc.next();
        if (n.startsWith("'") && !n.endsWith("'")) {
            n = n + sc.findInLine(".+?'");
        }
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```