# Scanning 2 Different Data Types Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a data file that is a list of names followed by "*****" and then continues with integers. How do I scan the names and then break with the asterisks, followed by scanning the integers?

Answer (score 2):

This question might help : [Splitting up data file in Java Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214206/splitting-up-data-file-in-java-scanner)

Use the [Scanner.useDelimiter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29) method, put "*****" as the delimiter, like this for example :

```
sc.useDelimiter("*****");
```

**OR**

Alternative :

1. Read the whole string
2. Split the string using [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)
3. Resulting String array will have index 0 contain the names and index 1 contain the integers.

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work for you

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(<INPUT_STR>).useDelimiter("[*****]");
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            // For Integer
        } else {
            // For String
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this seems a tedious thing, I think this would solve the issue without worrying if the split returns anything, and the out of bounds.

```
final String x = "abc****12354";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]*[a-z]*\\*{4}");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
    final Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("\\*{4}[0-9]*");
    final Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(x);
    while (m1.find()) {
        System.out.println(m1.group());
    }
```

The first pattern match minus the last 4 stars (can be substring-ed out) and the second pattern match minus the leading 4 stars (also can be removed) would give the request fields.