# Regular expression to replace all pipe symbols between double quotes

Tags: java, regex, delimiter

I have the following string received as part of a file record

`1234567890|ABCDE|""|"01|02|03|"|453625|New Account|05736372828|NA|||AT|899`

The record is using pipe symbol `|` as a delimiter, however if the `|` is appearing within the data that is inside double quotes `"` it should be not be split and considered as single text e.g. `"01|02|03"`

I am using regex to try converting the `"01|02|03|"` data into `"01,02,03,"` before splitting the string using `|` delimiter, however the regex is not working as expected.

Below is the code snippet written for the requirement using reference from another SO question [Regular expression, replace all commas between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658538/regular-expression-replace-all-commas-between-double-quotes)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String orig = "1234567890|ABCDE|\"\"|\"01|02|03|\"|453625|New Account|05736372828|NA|||AT|899";
    String regex = "(?<=\")([^\"]+?)\\|([^\"]+?)(?=\")";  
    String old = orig;
    String result = orig.replaceAll(orig, "$1,$2");  
    while (!result.equalsIgnoreCase(old)){  
        old = result;  
        result = result.replaceAll(regex, "$1,$2");  
    }
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

The output from the above code is `1234567890|ABCDE|""|"01,02,03|"|453625|New Account|05736372828|NA|||AT|899` which is not as expected. The `|` after `03` in `"01|02|03|"` is not getting replaced with `,`.

Appreciate if someone can help correct the regex or share an altogether new regex that would help split the string by retaining the `|` within the `"`.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex solution? There are other ways of doing it without regex, e.g. use a CSV library (setting the delimiter to pipe, obv).

Comment: The direction might be wrong. Why would you want to modify the orginal data to just to have an easy way to split it?

Comment: Use a proper CSV parser.

Comment: This is the basically same problem as handing commas within fields in CSV files. There are several questions about this topic. Try searching on this site for `[regex] csv comma is:q`.

Comment: Why bother with regex when most CSV parsers can do this out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regular expression `(\"([^\"]*)\")` to capture content within double quotes, excluding the quotes themselves. Then iterate the string, replace any `pipes` captured with `commas`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String orig = "1234567890|ABCDE|\"01|02|03|\"|453625|New Account|05736372828|NA|||AT|899";

        String regex = "\"([^\"]*)\"";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(orig);

        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

        while (matcher.find()) {
            String replacement = matcher.group(1).replace('|', ',');
            matcher.appendReplacement(result, Matcher.quoteReplacement("\"" + replacement + "\""));
        }

        matcher.appendTail(result);

        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Output `1234567890|ABCDE|"01,02,03,"|453625|New Account|05736372828|NA|||AT|899`

Answer (score -1):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern to match only pipes that are followed by an odd number of double quotes, providing that the double quotes are properly paired:

```
result = orig.replaceAll("\\|(?=[^\"]*\"(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)", ",")
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/s0TOq0